# How to run this Angular project with plain Javascript

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-material

I have this `Angular` project:

```
$ mkdir angular-material-select
$ cd angular-material-select
$ git clone git@github.com:napolev/angular-material-select.git .
$ npm install
$ ng serve
```

which uses the `<mat-select />` from `Material Design`.

Original example: https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#resetting-the-select-value

Isolated example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/qodvbqymxae

My goal is to use the component: `<mat-select />` with plain `Javascript` without serving with `ng` like: `ng serve`. I wanna use it in the following way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8" />

<!-- BEGIN of {Angular, Material Design, etc.} dependencies -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..." />
<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
<!-- END of {Angular, Material Design, etc.} dependencies -->

<script type="text/javascript">
// BEGIN OF Angular BLOCK
// ...
// ... (if necessary)
// ...
// END OF Angular BLOCK
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <!-- ... -->

    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select placeholder="State">
            <mat-option>None</mat-option>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">{{state}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <!-- ... -->

</body>

</html>
```

I want something similar to this working example (`Angular 1`):

Live code: https://napolev.github.io/angular-material-select/datepicker.html

Source code: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/napolev/angular-material-select/master/datepicker.html

Comment: Find another datepicker that meets your dependency requirements or hire a developer to refactor one that suits your needs

Comment: I may be missing the point here, but if you build the project (with `ng build`), it will compile the typescript into javascript, and you can open the `index.html` file in your browser, without the need for `ng serve`